# Backpressure with flatmap in io reactor

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-data-cassandra

We are using springboot 2.0 with reactive spring data cassandra module.
We have following piece of code

```
Flux.range(1,10000).flatMap(this::getData).subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
            subscription.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void hookOnNext(List<Data> value) {
            request(1);
        }
    });

public Mono<List<Data>> getData(int n){
    //cassandra reactive call to get List of data
}
```

Problem we are facing is getData is called for maximum integer values even we have backpressure using BaseSubscriber. Due to this requests are timedout at cassandra. I think as we are using flatmap and getData is returning mono, backpressure is not applied. We have to use flatmap, as on mono error we are returning mono.empty to keep data requested for rest of the integers in flux. Can someone please help to apply backpressure in this scenario?

Comment: is `getData` really requested for `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? can you add a `.log()` to your `getData()` to confirm?

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of `flatMap` in which you can set the `concurrency` parameter (actually more of a parallelism factor) and the `prefetch` parameter (which defaults to 256). The last one is the amount the inner flux is requested on the first time, so you could set it to `1`.